# CQL Concatenation

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter

I would like to use concatenation on a CQL filter being passed to Geoserver, if the filter I was trying to achieve were for Postgres it would look like this:

house_name||house_number||streetname ILIKE 'The Any House 1 Any Street Anytown'

Can this be done with CQL for Geoserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [string concatenation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions) function. For example:

```
concatenate(CODE,NAME)='6300Ashreigney'
```